# Wrong Electrum private keys when using BIP-84?

Tags: electrum

I'm running pre-release version [d8dad7](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/commit/d8dad74267fe1bdcd98dce0d79e2196f7ced60dc) of Electrum that supports BIP-84 HD derivations.

When exporting private keys, I'm getting WIF keys that are different from the expected output generated by [bx](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer) or [iancoleman.io/bip39](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/).

#### Example

Create a new Electrum wallet by importing the mnemonic `tumble mistake gift ill hungry chunk suggest limit artwork filter peanut exhaust` with path `m/84'/0'/0'`.

The first pubkey (`m/84'/0'/0'/0/0`) is correctly generated:
`0300e0d90c8cb3e1bb7b7a82bd1a118c615d97c03dd3c5f607636e9305a22bbd3e`

`bx` shows the same key:

```
mnemonic="tumble mistake gift ill hungry chunk suggest limit artwork filter peanut exhaust"
echo $mnemonic | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new | bx hd-private -i 84 -d | bx hd-private -i 0 -d | bx hd-private -i 0 -d | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 |bx hd-to-public | bx hd-to-ec
```

In Electrum, the corresponding private key (`Wallet -> Private keys -> export`) is displayed as `LEF3hMKjm4E1MVsGZLpPb5Bjza8p7qqRYn4GzjyCK8Uo1CX8w3z2`.

But `bx` ...

```
 echo $mnemonic | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new | bx hd-private -i 84 -d | bx hd-private -i 0 -d | bx hd-private -i 0 -d | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-private -i 0 | bx hd-to-wif
```

... (like [iancoleman.io/bip39](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/)) gives another result:
`L5fR8BxqauJsNyrW1GRVnu6Fk8wAHRZhPLS9SHd6pej5isKt3qJH`

Is this a bug in Electrum or an export scheme that differs from the regular WIF?

This discrepancy in private keys doesn't appear when using `m/44'/0'/0'` as the derivation path in Electrum.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help by marking your answer as accepted unless you are doubtful that it is entirely correct so that the question does not remain "unanswered".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electrum uses a modified WIF that encodes the address type:

[Release notes](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/42a16d9c3e19785ad39f272517aa2ce54b9e0f7f/RELEASE-NOTES#L126-L139)

[Source](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/42a16d9c3e19785ad39f272517aa2ce54b9e0f7f/lib/bitcoin.py#L524)

Comment: You can convert between private key types using [this script](https://gist.github.com/AbdussamadA/dd46a31033f2eb9e5189ed0b849c4be8)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [code](https://github.com/Anderson-Juhasc/bip84) that follows the bip84 and I advise to generate electrum addresses using ZPub.